# Unable to get existing session in .net with Chrome & Firefox where as it is working IE 9

Tags: jquery, .net, google-chrome, firefox

I am unable to get existing session in .net web service using Firefox and Chrome, where as it is working in IE 9 or higher.

**Case:**
I am using Session.IsNewSession property to check weather session is new or existing. This property gives me false if session is existing using Internet Explorer, where as in Firefox and Chrome it is giving me true.

In my web service I don't have any session variable stored in this, I just wanted to check weather session is new or existing.

I am calling this web service using .ajax call.

```
 [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json), WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public string GetBusinessPartnerByKey(string CardCode, string dbName)
    {
        General.WriteLog("Getting BP by key for : " + CardCode, "BP");
        //if (General.Company != null)
        //if (Session["Session"]!=null)
        if (!Session.IsNewSession) //here I am getting true in IE and false in Firefox and Chrome.
        {
            try
            {
               //do some stuff
             }
            catch (SqlException e1)
            {
                return code.General.Response("-1", e1.Message, "");
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
                return code.General.Response("-1", e1.Message, "");
            }
        }
        else
            return code.General.Response("-99", "Session Expire", "");
    }
```

This is my JavaScript snippet

```js
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ClientURL + "/GetBusinessPartnerByKey",
        data: JSON.stringify({ CardCode: cardcode, dbName: $.session.get("dbName") }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
        dataType: "json",
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            
            try {
                var msg = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                $(this).MessageBox('error', msg.Message);
            }
            catch (e) {
                $(this).MessageBox('error', xhr.responseText);
            }

            return true;
        },
        success: function (data) {
            xml = $.parseXML(data.d);
            $BP = $(xml);
            $BusinessPartner = $BP;
            if ($BP.find('Result').text() == '0') {
                 //do some success stuff
                }
            }
            else {
                if ($BP.find('Result').text() == "-99") {
                    //do some session exipration stuff
                }
                else {
                     $(this).MessageBox('error', $BP.find('Message').text());
                }
            }
     
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved, by doing some tweak in global.asax file.